Semver LRU is not a constructor in yarn workspace
I have a project that I migrated from a standalone npm package to a yarn package in a workspace. My config is working correctly for building and type-checking, but when I try to run yarn test, my test suite fails with
    TypeError: LRU is not a constructor

      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/semver/classes/range.js:202:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/semver/classes/comparator.js:141:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/semver/index.js:29:20)
      at _jestSnapshot (../node_modules/@jest/expect/build/index.js:15:16)
      at createJestExpect (../node_modules/@jest/expect/build/index.js:30:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@jest/expect/build/index.js:39:20)

It seems like its an issue with versioning or configuration for the semver or lru-cache packages, but I'm unable to resolve it. I've run yarn add semver --dev and yarn add lru-cache --dev to see if I can resolve the issue, but it is persisting.
Here is the root level package.json:
{
  // name, version, repository, author, and license omitted
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "webapp",
  ],
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.1.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@jest/expect": "^29.7.0",
    "semver": "^7.6.0"
  }
}

And then in webapp/package.json
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest --runInBand",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...,
    "lru-cache": "^10.2.0",
   },
   "packageManager": "yarn@4.1.1"
}

There is no tsconfig or jest config at the root level. In the webapp directory, the config looks like:
tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx",],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
    "ts-auto-mock": {
        "createMock": {
            "properties": "fake"
        }
    }
}

jest.config.js
const nextJest = require("next/jest");
const createJestConfig = nextJest({ dir: "./" });
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = createJestConfig({
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.next/", "<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.*/__mocks__"],
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "node",
    moduleDirectories: [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules",
        "<rootDir>/../node_modules",
        "<rootDir>/src",
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.[tj]sx?$": "@swc/jest",
    },
    workerIdleMemoryLimit: "1024MB",
    testMatch: ["**/tests/**/test_*.(ts|tsx|js)"],
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
    setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/tests/setup.ts"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/tests/setupAfterEnv.ts"],
    cacheDirectory: ".jest/cache",
    cache: true,
    verbose: true,
});

Before, the root-level node_modules was not being recognized, but now it is. However, i am unable to resolve the issue regarding LRU not being a constructor.

In my case I was unsure what the export structure for lru-cache was, so I tried to log the output
console.log(LRU);

And saw
{ LRUCache: [class LRUCache] }

So my fix was to simply update the import statement to
const LRU = require('lru-cache').LRUCache;

Hope it will help somebody!
